# Getting a date and time input in Eastern Time and converting to UTC timestamp in Java

Tags: java, datetime, epoch, milliseconds

I have a simple web interface that takes a date and time in the form of "2009/10/09 11:00" or "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm". The time (from the user's standpoint) is in Eastern Time.

I want to be able to take this string, convert it to a UTC timestamp, so I can take this timestamp and query our NoSQL database based on the specified time.

My code is as follows:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startSearchTime, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
    LocalDateTime utcTime = dateTime.plusHours(4);
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(utcTime.toString());
    System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli());
```

I am getting the string from UI and storing it in 'startSearchTime'. I convert it from Eastern Time to UTC by adding 4 hours. I then attempt to create an instant object and parse the string and get epoch milliseconds but the exception I get is:

"Text '2015-10-16T14:00z' could not be parsed"

With this new Java 8 DateTime API, I thought this task would be easy, what am I missing?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33179483/642706) by Yasmani Llanes is basically correct. I’ll expound.

## `LocalDateTime` != UTC Moment

A [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is not a real date-time, it is not tied to the time line. It has no real meaning until you adjust it into a time zone to determine a point on the time line, a moment. Your code, `LocalDateTime utcTime`, with your choice of variable name, shows you have conflated a "local" date-time with being a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) moment. It is not. One is a vague idea, the other is real. (well, real in the Newton sense, not so much in the Einstein Relativistic sense ;-) )

So, the output of the [`LocalDateTime::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--) is not a fully-formed string as expected by the `Instant.parse` method. Specifically, it has no data pertaining to an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) nor [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). The previous paragraph explains why **this is a feature not a bug**.

What you want is a `ZonedDateTime` which is basically an `Instant` (a moment on the timeline in UTC) plus a `ZoneId` (a time zone).

> `ZonedDateTime` = `Instant` + `ZoneId`

A time zone is an offset-from-UTC (hours and minutes) *plus* a set of rules and anomalies (such as [Daylight Saving Time, DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)) for past, present, and future adjustments.

> `ZoneId` = offset-from-UTC + adjustment-rules

You are correct to go through [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) in the java.time framework, and this is where it gets a bit confusing. Logically, we should be able to parse directly from an input String to a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). But there is the issue of an input string without any time-zone info may not be valid for a particular zone because of adjustment-rules. For example, in the Spring when we "spring-ahead" with Daylight Saving Time, in the United States jumping an hour ahead at the stroke of 2 AM, there is no "02:38" or "20:54" on that day. The clock jumps from 01:59.59.x to 03:00:00.0.

My understanding is that the java.time framework wants to handle this adjustment via a `LocalDateTime` object being passed to `ZonedDateTime` rather than have `ZonedDateTime` handle it directly while parsing. Two steps: (1) Parse string into `LocalDateTime`, (2) Feed `LocalDateTime` object and `ZoneId` object to `ZonedDateTime`. To correctly handle an input string with "20:54" that day, we need parse it as a `LocalDateTime`, then ask `ZonedDateTime` to use the specified time zone to make an adjustment (resulting in "03:54", I think -- read the class doc for details and logic used in adjustment behavior).

So we need to add to your code, calling `ZonedDateTime`. Using the `LocalDateTime` object you created, we need to specify a `ZoneId` object for `ZonedDateTime` to use in completing the transformation to a `ZonedDateTime`.

### Proper Time Zone Names

You said the input string is in "[Eastern Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone)". I'm afraid to tell you there is no such thing. The "EST", "EDT", and other such 3-4 letter codes are not official, not standardized, and not unique. You need to learn to use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Perhaps you mean [`America/New_York`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/New_York) (note the underscore) or [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal) or some such zone. I will arbitrarily go with New York.

### Variable Naming

Note how I've changed your variable names. Naming variables is generally quite important for clarity and later maintenance, but even more so for date-time work.

### ISO 8601

By the way, a better way to exchange data of date-time values via strings is to use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats such as `2015-10-15T13:21:09Z`. These formats include an offset-from-UTC such as the `Z` (Zulu, UTC) shown in previous sentence. The java.time framework wisely extends the ISO 8601 formats by appending the name of the time zone in brackets. Passing around date-time strings with no offset or time zone info is asking for trouble.

### Example code.

Here is some sample code in Java 8. First we parse the string into a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
// Parse input string into a LocalDateTime object.
String input = "2009/10/09 11:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm" );
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse ( input , formatter );
```

Transform that amorphous `LocalDateTime` into an actual moment on the time line by assigning a time zone. We assume that input string represents the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) in [Poughkeepsie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poughkeepsie,_New_York) which uses the New York time zone. So we get a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) object for New York time zone.

```
// Specify the time zone we expect is implied for this input string.
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/New_York" );
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = ZonedDateTime.of ( localDateTime , zoneId );
```

You can easily adjust into other time zones. I'll arbitrarily show [India time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) as provides a contrast in two ways: ahead of UTC rather than behind, and its offset is not in whole hours (`+05:30`).

```
// For fun, adjust into India time, five and a half hours ahead of UTC.
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = zdtNewYork.withZoneSameInstant ( ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

We can do date-time calculation like adding four hours. Because we have a `ZonedDateTime`, that class handles adjustments needed for anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

```
// Get a moment four hours later.
ZonedDateTime later = zdtNewYork.plusHours ( 4 );  // DST and other anomalies handled by ZDT when adding hours.
```

For a UTC time zone, you can go either of two ways.

- Assign a time zone as you would for any other time zone, but note the handy constant defined in [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) (a subclass of [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)).
- Or, alternatively, extract the `Instant` from within the `ZonedDateTime`. An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.

Either way represents the same moment on the timeline. But notice in output below how each has a different format used by default in their respective `toString` implementation.

```
// To get the same moment in UTC time zone, either adjust time zone or extract Instant.
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = zdtNewYork.withZoneSameInstant ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
Instant instant = zdtNewYork.toInstant ();
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input );
System.out.println ( "localDateTime: " + localDateTime );
System.out.println ( "zdtNewYork: " + zdtNewYork );
System.out.println ( "zdtKolkata: " + zdtKolkata );
System.out.println ( "zdtUtc: " + zdtUtc );
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant );
System.out.println ( "later: " + later );
```

When run.

```
input: 2009/10/09 11:00
localDateTime: 2009-10-09T11:00
zdtNewYork: 2009-10-09T11:00-04:00[America/New_York]
zdtKolkata: 2009-10-09T20:30+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
zdtUtc: 2009-10-09T15:00Z
instant: 2009-10-09T15:00:00Z
later: 2009-10-09T15:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

## Database Query

As for querying a database, search StackOverflow as that has been handled exhaustively already. Upshot: In the future JDBC should be able to use the java.time data types shown here. Until then, convert to a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object. Convenient conversion methods provided for you, such as [`java.sql.Timestamp.from( Instant instant )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( zdtNewYork.toInstant () );
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, one of the best explanations I've seen on SO in awhile!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the text you're trying to parse is not in the format an `Instant` is supposed to be. You're missing the seconds and the Nanoseconds. A valid `String` would be something like "2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z".

You should use [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-) on your `LocalDateTime` instead.